# Shell script doesn't fail when calling routine that is not installed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, dockerfile

I have a simple shell script for installing Jenkins plugins:

```
installPlugin() {
    {...}
}

  for f in ${plugin_dir}/*.hpi ; do
    #without optionals
    deps=$( unzip -p ${f} META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | tr -d '\r' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n //g' | grep -e "^Plugin-Dependencies: " | awk '{ print $2 }' | tr ',' '\n' | grep -v "resolution:=optional" | tr '\n' ' ' )
    for plugin in $deps; do
      installPlugin "$plugin" 1 && changed=1
    done
  done
```

I'm calling this script from a Dockerfile like so:

```
RUN JENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME \
    http_proxy=$http_proxy \
    https_proxy=$https_proxy \
    $JENKINS_HOME/install_plugin.sh \
    ace-editor:1.1 \
```

Even though the **unzip** routine is not installed in the Dockerfile, when I run `docker build` the output is still SUCCESSFUL even though unzip is missing. I would like to fail the build if the following step fails:

```
deps=$( unzip -p ${f} META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | tr -d '\r' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n //g' | grep -e "^Plugin-Dependencies: " | awk '{ print $2 }' | tr ',' '\n' | grep -v "resolution:=optional" | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

Any help is much appreciated!

LE

The script outputs the following:

```
/var/jenkins/install_plugin.sh: line 62: unzip: command not found

 deps=
```

However, the docker build doesn't fail even if that script failed:

```
Successfully built 54f5a5ec567d
```

Comment: What is the current value of "deps"?

Comment: to check unzip exit status add `|| exit 1` after unzip command, outside parentheses because in sub shell, but as it's a pipe the exit status of pipe is the last command maybe use also `set -o pipefail`

Comment: You might want to `set -e` so that your script exits in error on the first error. That'd require using `|| true` on command raising expected errors you don't want to stop execution for.

Comment: @Aaron I already have [set -e] at the beginning of the script, I've just removed it for clarity when posting. [set -e -o pipefail] seems to work in the sense that the build now fails but it fails even if unzip is installed

Comment: Ah yes you need pipefail indeed (or you could use `type unzip >/dev/null` just before the pipeline which uses `unzip`). If it always fail it means at least one of the commands exit with a non zero exit code, I think you should debug which it is (set -x might help).

Comment: @Aaron [type unzip >/dev/null] just before the declaration of deps in the script works! It now fails if unzip is missing. Is [set -o pipefail] the only option I have if I want the script to fail if there are any other issues?

Comment: If you want it to fail at the first non-zero exit code wether it's located in a pipe or not yes. Note however that without pipefail `set -e` will still exit the script if the *last* command of a pipeline returns a non-zero exit code, so you could break a pipeline in multiples ones where you'd make sure the commands that can fail are at the end of a pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing an empty check like this:

```
 for f in ${plugin_dir}/*.hpi ; do

    manifestMf=$(unzip -p ${f} META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | tr -d '\r')
    if [ $manifestMf=="" ]; then
        echo "Invalid META-INF/MANIFEST inside $f"
        exit 1
    fi;

    #without optionals
    deps=$(echo $manifestMf | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n //g' | grep -e "^Plugin-Dependencies: " | awk '{ print $2 }' | tr ',' '\n' | grep -v "resolution:=optional" | tr '\n' ' ' )
    # with optionals
    #deps=$( unzip -p ${f} META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | tr -d '\r' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n //g' | grep -e "^Plugin-Dependencies: " | awk '{ print $2 }' | tr ',' '\n' | tr '\n' ' ' )
    for plugin in $deps; do
      installPlugin "$plugin" 1 && changed=1
    done
  done
done
```